# How Do I Convert from Map Coordinates from SWEREF99 TM to WGS84 Using R?

Tags: r, google-maps, coordinates, gis, wgs84

I am trying to use the [`sf`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html) package for R to convert the coordinates North 6855790, East 557541 from coordinate reference sysstem [SWEREF99 TM](https://www.lantmateriet.se/en/geodata/gps-geodesi-och-swepos/reference-systems/two-dimensional-systems/SWEREF-99-projektioner) to [WGS84](https://earth-info.nga.mil/?dir=wgs84&action=wgs84) and expecting the output North 61.830576°, East 16.092562° (in decimal, or North 61° 49′ 50,07″, East 16° 5′ 33,22″ in degrees, minutes, and seconds, although I would prefer decimal), as I get when using [this website](https://rl.se/rt90). I am, however, getting North 64.54803°, East 3.262454°.

The EPSG codes for SWEREF99 TM and WGS84 should be [3006](https://epsg.io/3006) and [4326](https://epsg.io/4326) respectively, as far as I understand.

For context: I plan to apply this conversion to a large dataset of coordinates using `dplyr`, once it works, so using the conversion website mentioned above is not practical. Alternative solutions, not using the `sf` package, would also work.

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried:

```r
# This part’s here for reproducibility.
# Ignore it if you already have sf installed
chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
install.packages('sf')

# The actual code.
library(sf)
data.frame(x = 6855790, y = 557541) |>
  st_as_sf(coords = c('x', 'y')) |>
  st_set_crs(3006) |>
  st_transform(4326)
```

Which gives me the following output:

```r
## Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
## Geometry type: POINT
## Dimension:     XY
## Bounding box:  xmin: 64.54803 ymin: 3.262454 xmax: 64.54803 ymax: 3.262454
## Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
##                    geometry
## 1 POINT (64.54803 3.262454)
```

I searched the forums before posting. For example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591493/transforming-coordinates-using-r-sweref-to-wgs84) is similar but uses the package `rdal`, which [is no longer on CRAN as of October 16, 2023](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch values

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
data.frame(x = 557541, y = 6855790) |>
  st_as_sf(coords = c('x', 'y')) |>
  st_set_crs(3006) |>
  st_transform(4326)
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 16.09256 ymin: 61.83058 xmax: 16.09256 ymax: 61.83058
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>                    geometry
#> 1 POINT (16.09256 61.83058)
```

That is `c("longitude", "latitude")`.
Looks promising

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

data.frame(x = 557541, y = 6855790) |>
  st_as_sf(coords = c('x', 'y')) |>
  st_set_crs(3006) |>
  st_transform(4326) -> pt

swe <- ne_countries(country = "sweden", scale = "large", returnclass = "sf")

ggplot(data = swe) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = pt)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Of course it makes sense that the east coordinate would be x and north y. I clearly got confused by the convention of writing coordinates in the order N/S, E/W on maps and X, Y on other coordinate system.